# Stored procedure works in SQL Server/SSRS query designer. Report body is empty

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that runs successfully in SQL Server that is not loading anything into the body of the report. There are only 4 parameters to this procedure, 2 varchars and 2 ints.

I have verified the following:

1. The stored procedure works in SQL Server
2. The stored procedure works in SSRS when using Query Designer
3. The stored procedure shows as being executed and completed in SQL Server Profiler
4. Running what is shown in the SQL Server Profiler does return the expected results
5. There is no filtering on the table containing the results
6. There is no visibility restrictions on the table containing the results
7. The connection to the database is successful using "Test connection" [as mentioned here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/501e68b2-ba7c-4031-92a7-2c0335f9fb0a/report-does-not-run-stored-procedure?forum=sqlreportingservices)
8. I have added a second different dataset into the report and it is showing in the body with no problems.
9. I have recompiled the procedure [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43776487/13342846) and it is still not showing in the report.
10. There are no multi valued parameters, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461273/ssrs-shows-no-records-in-report-but-query-returns-results) is mostly irrelevant.
11. We are not using Visual Studio, so there is no .DATA files like [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464682/13342846)

However for the life of me, I can not get anything from this stored procedure to show up in the body of the report.

Due to legal reasons, the stored procedure cannot be posted in this question as it was part of a software our company is using. We have permission from them to use the procedure to make the SSRS Report for our needs.

Comment: Since you've verified proc is being called and returns rows, I suggest you focus your troubleshooting efforts on the SSRS side.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the permissions that the procedure is running under when called under SSRS, so as RLS, or perhaps the language settings is causing a string literal date that isn't in an unambiguous format to be interpreted to a different value than intended.

Comment: I would check the connection/credentials of the datasource on the SSRS server to start with. It might be that it is not using the credentials you expect or it is pointing to another database/server. DataSources are not overwritten by default.

Comment: @Stu Thank you for the suggestion, after doing this I found that the user that SSRS is using is returning 0 rows, but when running as myself it returns the desired data. Make that the answer so I can mark it for you please

Answer (score 0):

Further diagnostics and logging are always useful.

You could have the procedure log additional data to a dedicated table for review later.

Useful data would be that which is related to the user's session based on `@@spid` and the system views *sys.dm_exec_sessions, sys.dm_exec_requests, sys.dm_exec_input_buffer()* such as statement start time, any blocking spids, wait_types. Also check the connection level properties are consistent and as expected eg *quoted_identifier*, ansi-settings etc.

You could also log information about the executing queries such as Rows Affected `@@rowcount` and the values of any parameters or intermediate values.